# Error when update record data in odoo contact details through website

Tags: python, xml, odoo

so im trying to add new field in my contact module, and i want to show it in front-end website contact details, i already can fetch the data from db to show it in website but when i want to update the record data, i got error
< Unknown field 'umur,lama_kerja,grade,talent' >

this is my python code

```
class ModificationContact(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

umur = fields.Char('Umur', store=True)
lama_kerja = fields.Char('Lama Kerja', store=True)
grade = fields.Char('Grader', store=True)
talent = fields.Char('Talent', store=True)
```

and then my xml code for template

```
<template id="my_custom_details" inherit_id="portal.portal_my_details" name="Update Contact Details">
          <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('col-lg-12')]" position="after">
            <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('umur') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="umur">Umur</label>
                <input type="text" name="umur" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('umur') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="umur or partner.umur" />
            </div>
            <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('lama_kerja') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="lama_kerja">Lama Kerja</label>
                <input type="text" name="lama_kerja" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('lama_kerja') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="lama_kerja or partner.lama_kerja" />
            </div>
            <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('grade') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="grade">Grade</label>
                <input type="text" name="grade" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('grade') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="grade or partner.grade" />
            </div>
            <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('talent') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="talent">Talent</label>
                <input type="text" name="talent" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('talent') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="talent or partner.talent" />
            </div>
        </xpath>
</template>
```

this is my xml code for show the added field

```
<data>
<record id="view_inherit_modifier_contact" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.inherit.modifier.contact</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       
        <xpath expr="//field[@name ='category_id']" position="after">
            <field name="umur" string="Umur"/>
            <field name="lama_kerja" string="Lama Kerja"/>
            <field name="grade" string="Grade"/>
            <field name="talent" string="Talent"/>
        </xpath>
</field>
</record>
</data>
```

pls tell me if i have something wrong in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo shows the error because it failed to [validate](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/portal/controllers/portal.py#L377-L380) the details form.

If one field is not present in `MANDATORY_BILLING_FIELDS` and `OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS`, Odoo will not save form data

To fix that, you can add your fields to the `OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS` list

***Example:***

```py
from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal


CustomerPortal.OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS += ['umur', 'lama_kerja', 'grade', 'talent']
```